# powershell invoke-command not working, but psexec does

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am trying to uninstall an old version of Flash on multiple PCs with a powershell script using the invoke-command cmdlet.  The script runs without errors, but flash is never uninstalled.  Here is what I am using:

```
$flash = get-content "C:\11.6.txt"
$flash | Foreach {
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {Start-Process cmd.exe "/c start /wait MsiExec.exe /X{346137E0-7160-403B-AD21-3FF01D25037B} /qn" -NoNewWindow}
Write-Host "Uninstall from $_ complete."}
else {
Write-Host "$_ is offline"
}
}
```

If I run the uninstaller via psexec it works fine:

```
start /wait msiexec.exe /X{346137E0-7160-403B-AD21-3FF01D25037B} /qn
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why invoke-command won't work.  I am relatively new to PowerShell so it could be something silly, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to executing code on a remote computer i have never been successful with Invoke-Command. However, PSExec has been nothing but good to me.

Try something like this. I can't test at the moment but let me know if it works for you.
Note: Change the FilePath location to your PSExec.exe location.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\PSExec.exe" -ArgumentList {"\\$ComputerNameHere CMD.exe '/C start /wait msiexec.exe /X{346137E0-7160-403B-AD21-3FF01D25037B} /qn'"}
```

Comment: thanks for trying!  I didn't work well at all.  I did some more digging and here is the code that ended up working: `$flashPuters = Get-Content "C:\11.8.800.txt"
foreach ($computer in $flashPuters) 
{
    if (test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
         & 'C:\PSTools\psexec.exe' @("\\$computer", 'msiexec.exe', '/X{BFBC6337-B7B9-4AEE-BC19-CA910EED755D}', '/qn')
         "Uninstall complete for $computer" >> C:\11.8.800.log 
    }else {  
    "$computer is not online" >> C:\Test.log
    } 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ended up working for me:

```
$flashPuters = Get-Content "C:\11.8.800.txt"
foreach ($computer in $flashPuters) 
{
if (test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
     & 'C:\PSTools\psexec.exe' @("\\$computer", 'msiexec.exe', '/X{BFBC6337-B7B9-4AEE-BC19-CA910EED755D}', '/qn')
     "Uninstall complete for $computer" >> C:\11.8.800.log 
}else {  
"$computer is not online" >> C:\11.8.800.log
}
```

}

Thank you to @HiTech for helping me!